Can't access shadowRoot
I want to pass a captcha on website https://sirus.one/#play and I need to set the solved captcha value in textarea.g-recaptcha-response -> div.innerText. TextArea has shadowRoot where website saving the response of recaptcha.
I tried to access shadowRoot like that:
document.querySelector("textarea.g-recaptcha-response").shadowRoot, but the result is null.
If I print the element in console it appears that shadowRoot exists

How to get the shadowRoot?

have you tried checking the documentation? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ShadowRoot

Are you sure the shadowRoot has been attacked with the mode option set to open? It will not be accessible otherwise

Since it is a captcha you are trying to solve I think it's a reasonable assumption that the shadow root has not been attached with the mode: open option. As such you will not be able to access it using the shadowRoot property


const div = document.querySelector('div');
const p = document.querySelector('p');

p.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});
div.attachShadow({mode: 'closed'});

console.log('Paragraph has accessible Shadow DOM:', !!p.shadowRoot); // true
console.log('Div has accessible Shadow DOM:', !!div.shadowRoot); // false
<p></p>
<div></div>




It was my mistake. I can't access shadowRoot created by browser. The solution is just to change the value of textarea: document.querySelector("#g-recaptcha-response").value = "123"
